# Inserting Unicode with a regex and sed

Tags: regex, bash, unicode, sed

I have a large text file containing a mix of words, numbers and Unicode characters. I would like to print this (current plan is with TeX), but I am having trouble with line breaking of long sequences of characters.

I plan to use `sed` with bash to rip though the file and replace runs of more than, say, 10 non-whitespace characters with the same run followed by a zero-width space (U+200B). I am having trouble putting the Unicode character in, everything else seems in order.

```
longStr=reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeealylongstr
echo $longStr | sed -re 's/(\S{10})/\1\u200b/g'
```

produces

```
reeeeeeeee200beeeeeeeeee200beeeeeeeeee200beeeeeeeeee200beeeealylon200bgstr
```

What is the right way to insert a Unicode character by code-point in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UTF-8 bytes instead.

Google or iconv will tell you that the code point `U+200B` is encoded in UTF-8 is `0xE2 0x80 0x8B`.

```
longStr=reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeealylongstr
echo $longStr | sed -re 's/(\S{10})/\1\xE2\x80\x8B/g'
```

Note that these characters don't render in a terminal, so if you just paste it into a shell, it will appear to do nothing.